# Azure webservice automatically adding NODE_OPTIONS environment variable causing jsreport to throw JsReportBinaryException

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, jsreport

I do currently have a working docker image using ASP.NET Core with jsreport on my local image, that does not work on a Azure App Service running Linux containers. The following error is thrown when any rendering is tried:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      jsreport.Local.JsReportBinaryException: Error rendering report: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:58const internalModuleStat = function (f) { return require('fs').internalModuleStat(f); };                                                               ^TypeError: require(...).internalModuleStat is not a function    at internalModuleStat (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:58:64)    at stat (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:137:18)    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:16)    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1296:12)    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:449:5)    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:73:3)    at internal/bootstrap/pkg.js:7:1
         at jsreport.Local.Internal.LocalUtilityReportingService.RenderAsync(String requestString, CancellationToken ct)
         at jsreport.AspNetCore.JsReportMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I have tracked down the difference between my machine an the Azure App Service to the following environment variable, that causes the same error on my local machine: (to a add, this environment variable seems to be added automatically by Azure)

```
-e NODE_OPTIONS="--require /agents/node/build/src/Loader.js"
```

I did not found any usefull information about this and did not find a way to remove nor to override it in the Azure Portal configuration either. A possible workaround would be to remove this environment variable the first time the container is started, but this does not seem like a good longtime solution. Is there a way to force Azure to not include this environment variable, to ignore it locally or am I missing something else here?

Update:
Using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NODE_OPTIONS", "");` at start does indeed "solve" this error, but still did not found any satisfing solution.

Update2:
I have found out, that it is caused by the Application Insights nodejs support. They have added the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable (see also https://newreleases.io/project/github/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/release/1.7.0) to load Application Insights as soon and reliable as possible. I do as of now have not found any solution to how to disable Application Insights for Nodejs nor why this is causing an Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original Answer was deleted.

The solution was to set `appInsights.defaultClient.config.disableAppInsights` to `true` in the App Service `Configuration`.